# Regex doesn't find a match with a pattern

Tags: html, .net, regex

In a C# project, Regex is behaving weirdly for me.

I have this method:

```
string RegTest()
    {
        string HTML = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"authenticity_token\" value=\"d27956cca6b75db4d8dd502d0569dd246455131c\">";
        Regex AuthRegex = new Regex(@"name=""authenticity_token"" value=""([A-Ba-b0-9/-]+)""");
        string Auth = AuthRegex.Match(HTML).Value;
        return Auth;
    }
```

For a reason I don't understand at all, the Regex doesn't find any match with this pattern. It just returns `""`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @ndn I thought that by using `@` I don't need to escape it. What is the correct way to escape it in the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```
[A-Ba-b0-9/-]+
```

What character ranges (`x-y`) basically do is get a set of all characters in between. In other words, `a-b` = all letters between `a` and `b`, aka only `a` and `b`. However,

```
d27956cca6b75db4d8dd502d0569dd246455131c
```

looks like a hex. Therefore, you should use

```
[A-Fa-f0-9-]+
```

instead.

Comment: OK, Thank you very much!

And now I've also noticed I wrote `A-B` instead of writing `A-Z` like I usually do... -_-